# How do I make a button add one view at a time?

Tags: swift, view, uibutton

I'm practicing creating an app that has 3 views. Each view has a button to hide itself. Now, I added a button outside the views to re-add them after I hide them, but, when i remove the views and I press it, it shows me all of the three views. I want it to add one view at a time (without removing the other views). What can I do? 
This is my code, I was even thinking about adding multiple add buttons but it wouldn't be clear.

```
      @IBAction func addViewButton(_ sender: Any) { 
    view1.isHidden = false
    view2.isHidden = false
    view3.isHidden = false
    }
```

Comment: You haven't really given enough specifics - the answer posted may be enough. But if you want to "tie" a view to a specific button, look into the `tag` property. That is exactly what it's for... give each button a specific tag, check it in the "common" function, and go from there!

Comment: What you actually need.. Can you attach any screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a variable like currentVisibleViews in your ViewController, and lets say at first there is only first one is visible so we start off the number as 1, and also add your views to an array to control easier:

```
var currentVisibleViews = 1
var viewArray = [UIView]()
```

In `viewDidLoad`, add your views to `viewArray`:

```
view1.isHidden = false
view2.isHidden = true
view3.isHidden = true

viewArray.append(view1)
viewArray.append(view2)
viewArray.append(view3)
```

Then in your button:

```
@IBAction func addViewButton(_ sender: Any) { 
    if currentVisibleViews > 2 {
        viewArray.forEach { (view) in
            view.isHidden = true
        }
        currentVisibleViews = 0
    } else {
        viewArray[currentVisibleViews].isHidden = false
        currentVisibleViews += 1
    }
}
```

Code above works as this:

1. First all views are visible
2. First tap will hide all views
3. Then each tap will make a view visible
4. Go to step 2 (once all views are visible)

By this way, you can only have one function to control all your views, it doesnt have to be IBAction anymore, it can be just a method of your ViewController

Comment: Wait, I'm a beginner, how do I create an array with UIViews?

Comment: Like I did in my answer, You have outlets of your views right? Just below them create the array like: `let viewArray = [view1, view2, view3]`

Comment: when I try I get a swift compiler error that says
<unknown>:0: error: cannot use instance member 'view1' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Comment: Sorry you need to create empty array then deploy views inside array in viewDidLoad, see my edited answer.

Comment: ook perfect, but what if I don't want to hide my views the first time but I just want the button to add them? ( the app starts with view1, the other two are initially hidden)

Comment: But the total number of views will be maximum 3 right?

Comment: Then it changes everything, also you need to specify the coordinates for new views, since you are going to need to create views programmatically. Because you dont know how many

Comment: I can't create them programmatically because my task requires to do them in the storyboard, anyway I guess I'll have 10 views or something like that...

Comment: Then you need to play around with currentVisibleViews initializing number, which should be 1 and then in viewDidLoad after deploying elements to the array, make all the views hidden except first one, it also requires to change button tapped function to be >= 9, now instead of 2. I will update my answer for 3 views initially 1 then you can change as you need.

Comment: It should add one at a time, are you sure your code is exactly same with mine? Double check and make sure it is. Or your button clicked twice somehow, can you debug and see if your button runs the code twice?

Comment: sure, I have another question, what if I want the button to never hide the views but instead to add, when possible other views (for example, pretend I close view3 and view4 and after i add the other views I want the button to readd view3 and view4 instead of closing them all)? do I have to use a loop?